# Setting highlighted text color in a row in a table with Java Swing

Tags: java, swing

I know we are almost in 2018 but I'm stuck at work having to use Java Swing.

I wanted to be able to highlight particular pieces of text in one or more rows. That was quite easy, as I could use html tags for that:

[image]

The problem as can be seen, though, is that when I select a row, the inverted colors are terrible. I would like to prevent having the foreground text color turning white when a row is selected (I would think that, for instance, keeping it black would be fine).

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: Could you try using the `<font color=black>` tag ?

Comment: @Berger: You're quite the master! So obvious, yet it worked. Can you put that as an answer?

Comment: What about [`JTable.setSelectionBackground(Color)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setSelectionBackground-java.awt.Color-) and [`JTable.setSelectionForeground(Color)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setSelectionForeground-java.awt.Color-)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a `<font>` tag , that is among the supported html tags .

e.g :

```
"<html><font color=\"black\">"+YourText+"</font></html>"
```

Some more information here :

[Multiple Strings colored in different way into the same cell of a JTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858267/multiple-strings-colored-in-different-way-into-the-same-cell-of-a-jtable)